Wordpress REST API - Create post not working with 401 response but list posts working
I have used miniOrange API Authentication plugin and configured JWT authentication -> JWT generation using HS256 Encryption.
I am able to fetch a token for a wordpress user (which is set as administrator) and then use the token to list posts using a cURL. This means the authentication is working fine.
However I am unable to do so using Postman directly (but ignoring this point).
curl 'http://<Domain>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?mo_rest_api_test_config=jwt_auth' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Cookie: fontSize=100; wp-settings-100=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26imgsize%3Dfull%26editor%3Dtinymce%26hidetb%3D0%26siteorigin_panels_setting_tab%3Dcontent%26advImgDetails%3Dhide; wp-settings-time-100=1713769862; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_0bb96e438546056053956b6eba75cc18=newuser%7C1714027806%7CsJuZdE7zvbhM17HcVGIR7xoBA5u0n7oyHaWdovDQUmu%7Cbd0b8572fffcf4a5148c1984eeaa31ebea1bef08e062284de4b6149953cb3b3d; wordpress_logged_in_0bb96e438546056053956b6eba75cc18=newuser%7C1714027806%7CsJuZdE7zvbhM17HcVGIR7xoBA5u0n7oyHaWdovDQUmu%7C022de159b8f6c80e5ded79e908ee447f9f2c51d861f4b9ca6749287bbaf61d72' \
  -H 'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Referer: http://<Domain>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mo_api_authentication_settings' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer <Token>' \
  --insecure ;

However, I am unable to create a post using the same token. Postman cURL -
curl --location 'http://www.aus.ac.in/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <Token>' \
--form 'title="Hello"' \
--form 'status="draft"'

Response
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}

I also tried turning off authentication of the /wp/v2/posts from the Protected Rest APIs configuration of the miniOrange plugin config, but now when I try without Authentication token only the list posts API end point works, while the create post keeps throwing the same error, as mentioned above.
Request
curl -X POST http://<domain>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ -d '{"title":"My New Title"; "status":"draft"}'

Response
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}

I also tried using a wordpress Superadmin user for the authentication. But it seems I am missing something.

It looks like there are two separate routes to this message, but both are just current_user_can() checks in class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php. I'd add error_log() trace to that to work out what's going wrong.

... unless this is being triggered by whatever endpoint protection miniOrange adds, in which case you'd need to ask them about that.

you can verify if you can make authenticated requests by requesting /wp-json/wp/v2/me and get a response describing who you are logged in as. If that works but your post creation does not then it's unlikely to be a REST API related problem and something more general, or using the incorrect user. Mini Orange plugin greatly complicates this though, there is an extremely high chance that nobody here can ever help you without paying for MiniOrange and becoming an expert in it https://plugins.miniorange.com/wordpress-rest-api-authentication, their support should have been your first call
